# activemq & Glassfish : InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too long

Tags: java, glassfish, activemq-classic

My systems has the following parts:

- Activemq 5.8.0
- 4 ear deployed on Glassfish 3.0
- A .net client that connects to a web service deployed on Glassfish

(none of these seems is using activemq)

Systems works perfectly for months, until it fails with a  InactivityIOException (ActiveMQ)

> 2015-03-11 08:23:17,369 WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:33130 > failed:
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was
>   inactive for too (>30000) long: tcp://127.0.0.1:33130 |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ
>   InactivityMonitor Worker

after a while Glassfish crash

> |2015-03-11T08:37:08.845+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=120519;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|2015-03-11
>   08:34:30,418 [0.1:61616@33130] ERROR ActiveMQEndpointWorker         -
>   Connection to broker failed: java.io.EOFException
>   javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException  at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1969)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1988)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onException(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:200)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
>     ... 1 more |#]
>   [#|2015-03-11T08:45:44.211+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023:
>   Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(4).|#]

i read [ActiveMQ:'channel inactive for too long' exceptions stop broker messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320022/activemqchannel-inactive-for-too-long-exceptions-stop-broker-messaging) but i don't want to stop InactivityMonitor, and setting a higher value for timeout don't solve my problem (just postpone it), question is : why i'm getting this inactivityException and why GF hang out?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the inactivityMonitor should be disabled. If you need it up and running on production, then you should configure this behaviour with a property in your config files.