# activemq-all.jar (5.14.0) does not works with Spring 4.3.6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, activemq-classic

Earlier I was using activemq-all-4.1.2.jar to fetch/listen from apache-activemq-5.14.0. But this leads me to the following exception:-

```
15-05-2017 18:50:32.685|WARN |AcitveMQ Connection Worker: ssl://BDNVM4APK756V02/X.X.X.X:61616|Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection|[SingleConnectionFactory.java:322]
javax.jms.JMSException: Channel was inactive for too long.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:46)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1525)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1541)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:114)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:147)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onException(InactivityMonitor.java:156)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.readCheck(InactivityMonitor.java:102)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.access$000(InactivityMonitor.java:35)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor$1.run(InactivityMonitor.java:51)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:431)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:198)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:189)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:213)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
        at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too long.
        ... 10 more
```

So I upgrade my jar to activemq-all-5.14.0.jar as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320022/activemqchannel-inactive-for-too-long-exceptions-stop-broker-messaging)
but then I got the following exception:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jioTUConfig': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.resetAdviceMonitor(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.setBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 38 more
```

I can't use any building tool inside my organisation due to network security.

I am using spring-4.3.6 version.
Specifically for JMS it is spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar and spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. Apparently apache-activemq-5.14.0 latest jar uses few Spring(4.1.9) related jars and some other commonly used jars like self4j,log4j,jsypt etc. Removing my Spring-4.3.6 jars and other jars which are common to both from the classpath resolved the issue.

To check what jars exactly it is using you need to extract the apache-activemq-X.X.X.jar to "apache-activemq-X.X.X" folder and check the DEPENDENCIES file. The location will be

> apache-activemq-X.X.X/META_INF/DEPENDENCIES

**Update:-**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

activemq-all-X.X.X.jar contains spring , you can find the DEPENDENCIES
[image]

[image]
you should match the version eg:

Comment: i'm new with stackoverflow ~